# can't run blink code for raspberry pi pico using VsCode

Tags: python, raspberry-pi-pico

So i am trying to run a simple blink code on Raspberry Pi pico using VsCode and PicoGo extension when i run it i get ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'machine'
though when i run the same code in thonny it works just fine

```
from machine import Pin
from time import sleep

pin = Pin(25,Pin.OUT)

while True:
    pin.toggle()
    sleep(0.5)
```

when i run this i get ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'machine'

here's a picture to clear things up
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vHCxo.png)

Comment: please, no pictures of text ... copy the code listing and add to the question ... copy all of error message and add to the question

Comment: i don't think the problem is from the code because it works fine in thonny

Comment: It sounds as if vscode may be trying to run your code using your system python rather than running it in micropython on the pico.

Comment: how can i make it run in micropython? @larsks

Answer (score 1):

If you try using the VS Code "Run and Debug" button...

[image]

...this will try running your code with the `python` interpreter on your *host*. In order to run your code on the Pico, you need to use the "Run" button in the PicoGo control bar at the bottom of the window:

[image]

This will send the code to the Pico and execute it there.